# Sobrecarga de operadores en javascript

Tags: javascript, operador, sobrecarga

Tengo una duda. ¿Como se puede sobrecargar el operador `=` o el operador `+` en Javascript?

```
class Vector{
        constructor(x,y){
           this.x = x
           this.y = y
}   
        add(a){

}     
        equal(){
} 
}
```

Es para usar de la forma `a = b` y no `a.equal(b)`

Comment: para eso existe ```a==b``` el cual compara los valores, tambien puedes usar ```a===b``` el cual evaluara con mucho mas cuidado la expresion tomando en cuenta el tipo de dato

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Javascript` a diferencia de `Java` considera como un tipo primitivo a los `strings`, (es solo un dato curioso, ya que se que probablemente lo que uses no sean strings), por lo tanto puedes comparar de manera directa dos `strings` o `numeros` sin necesidad de ponerte a pensar o crear `metodos` para ello.

Simplemente debes usar el operador de comparación `==` o el operador de comparación estricta `===` para tu propósito.

```js
class Vector {

  constructor(x, y) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
  }

}

const vector = new Vector(25, 25);
console.log(vector.x === vector.y);
```

Donde la diferencia entre el operador `==` y `===` es principalmente que el operador de comparación estricta `===` también comprueba si el tipo de dato es el mismo, es decir, si ambos son `numeros` o `letras`.

```js
console.log("0" === 0);
```